# Error: Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | { valueOf(): number; }'?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I have this array type:

```
interface Details {
  Name: string;
  URL: string;
  Year: number;
}
interface AppState {
  data: Details[];
}
```

I am using D3 to create an x axis like this:

```
 createChart = () => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const width = 900,
      height = 600;

    // x-axis
    const x = d3
      .scaleLinear()
      .domain([
        d3.min(data, ({ Year }) => (Year ? Year - 1 : 0)), // ERROR
        d3.max(data, ({ Year }) => (Year ? Year + 1 : 0)) // ERROR
      ])
      .range([0, width]);
  };
```

On the marked lines using `d3.min` and `d3.max` I get the following error:

> Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | {
>   valueOf(): number; }'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
>   'number | { valueOf(): number; }'.

How do I make this work?

Comment: const {data} = this.state in the createChart might be undefined. If you are sure that data will never be undefined, the workaround is to use  d3.min(data as number, ....

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For your call to `d3.min()` the compiler will use the following [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-array/index.d.ts#L71):

```
export function min<T, U extends Numeric>(array: Iterable<T>, accessor: (datum: T, index: number, array: Iterable<T>) => U | undefined | null): U | undefined;
```

As you can see the function can return either `U`—in your case the type of `Details.Year`, i.e. `number`— or `undefined`. This, however, does not match the [type definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-scale/index.d.ts#L80) for the `.domain()` method which takes an array of either numbers or values coercible to numbers:

```
domain(domain: Array<number | { valueOf(): number }>): this;
```

This explains why you get the error. The same, obviously, holds true for `d3.max()`.

Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#min) the reasons for `d3.min()` to return `undefined` are rather limited:

> If the iterable contains no comparable values, returns undefined.

Given your code you are guaranteed to not run into this issue. For that reason you can safely cast the return values of `d3.min()` and `d3.max()` to `number`:

```
const x = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([
    d3.min(data, ({ Year }) => (Year ? Year - 1 : 0)) as number,  // cast to number
    d3.max(data, ({ Year }) => (Year ? Year + 1 : 0)) as number   // cast to number
  ])
  .range([0, width]);
```

Comment: TL;DR - add "as number" to coerce the result of the min and max functions to be number specifically rather than number | undefined.